# Getting error when i want to fetch bulk records

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

i am getting below error when i am trying to fetch more then 300000 records.
m using link to fetch records and using muiltiple classes. 
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

please let me know solution for this.

Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

In your case, memory allocated to JVM is not sufficient.
You can try by allocating more memory as follows :
Run --> Run Configurations --> select the "JRE" tab --> then enter -Xmx2048m

I believe you are running program with default VM arguments.
You can also figure out memory requirement by performing heap dump analysis or memory analyzer.

Even though this may resolve your issue temporarily (depending upon how much memory is required for 300000 records), I would suggest to do changes in your program, such as fetching records in batches.
I would suggest to refer to this post. 
[How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)